# OpenIddict local validation - multiple encryption keys for multiple Resourceservers

Tags: oauth, openiddict

when i use local validation instead of introspection in my project with OpenIddict
usually the Authserver and the Resourceserver are sharing one symmetric encryptionkey. However when i use more than one Resourceserver i would like to use more than one symmetric encryptionkey (each Resourceserver should have it's own encryptionkey). Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks for your help,
Nicolai

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported.

It may be supported in a future version, but it has important design considerations: e.g the JWT compact format doesn't support embedding multiple content encryption keys, which prevents issuing encrypted JWTs to different recipients/resource servers.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to share the secret with the resource servers (e.g. if you need to support 3rd party resource servers) you can use introspection.

But introspection has another drawback: I found no way to cache the introspection response in the openiddict validator. I don't think it is a good idea to have a roundtrip to the auth server on every API request. This could slow down high frequented API servers. Not sure if there is a simple solution for caching the response...